# Should output be encoded at the API or client level?

Tags: xss, rest, encoding

We are moving our Web app architecture to being microservice based. We have an internal debate as to whether an REST API that provides content (in JSON, let's say) should be looking to encode content to make it safe, or whether the consumers that take that content and display it (in HTML, for example, or otherwise use it) should be responsible for that encoding. The use case is to prevent XSS attacks and similar.

The provider stance is "Well, we can't know how to encode it for everyone, or how you're going to use the content, so of course the consumers should encode the content."

The consumer stance is "There is one provider and multiple consumers, so it's more secure to do it once in the providing API than to hope that every consumer does it."

Are there any generally accepted best practices on this and why?

Comment: This question is off-topic for security and more properly belongs on stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry I didn't spell it out, this is for XSS prevention and similar.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule, data when passing through "internal" processes (whatever that might mean to use) should be stored or encoded in whatever "internal" format makes sense. The format chosen is typically designed to minimize encoding/decoding steps and to prevent data loss.

Then, upon output, data is encoded using whatever *output* format makes sense. Preventing data loss is important, but also proper escaping and formatting is key here.

So for example, with internal APIs, data in binary format may be sufficent. But when you output JSON or HTML or XML or PDF, you have to encode and escape your data appropriately to fit the output format.

The important point here is that different output formats have different concepts of "safe". What's "safe" for HTML may not be safe for JSON, and what's safe for JSON may not be safe for SQL. Data is encoded upon output specifically so that you can use the proper encoding for the task. You cannot assume that this step is done for you ahead of time, nor should you put your output function in the position to determine whether or not encoding must be done. If you stick with the rule: "output function ALWAYS encodes for safety", then you will never have to worry about data injection attacks.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the two important points are the following:

- The encoding used by the provider MUST be specified with extreme clarity and precision in a reference document, so that all consumer implementors can know what to expect.
- Whatever default encoding is used by the provider MUST keep all needed information, i.e. still be amenable to transcoding by any consumer who would wish to do it.

If you follow these two rules then you will have done 95% of the job for reliability and security.

As for your specific question, a good practice is a middle-ground: the provider follows *by default* a "generic" encoding, but consumers can ask (optionally) for a specific encoding which the provider may then apply -- this allows the provider to support a number of dumb, lightweight clients of possibly different kinds and can be extended later on with extra encodings without breaking the API.

Answer (score 3):

I firmly believe it is both the consumer and the provider that need to do their part in being good citizens in the security space.

As the provider I want to make sure I deliver a secure product.  I don't need to know the context in which my client is going to use my product, all I need to know is how I am going to deliver it.  If my delivery is in JSON, then I can use that context to escape my data before sending it off, similarly for XML, plain text, etc.  Further more there are transport methods that aid in security already.  JSONP is one such delivery method.  This ensures the payload is consumed appropriately.

As the consumer, which by the way in our environment no one is the final consumer, we are all providers to the final end client (the end users via a web browser mostly.). Because of this we have to also secure the data at this end.  I would never trust a black box API to do this job for me, I would always make a point to ensure a secure payload.  There are many tools out there, the ESAPI project from OWASP comes to mind, that will aid in the sanitization by context of data.  Remember that you are eventually sending this data on to the end-user (browser) and if there is something awry you won't be able to pass the buck.  Your service will be viewed as the vulnerable one regardless of where the flaw lies.  Additionally, as the consumer, you may not always be able to rely on the black box provider to fix their flaws in a timely fashion.  What if their support is lacking or they have higher priorities.  Does that mean you continue to provide a known flaw to your end-users?

Security is about layers, and having safeguards at the source and end-points is always preferable.